# Django Rest Framework custom Permission Class with ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-rest-auth

I am trying to write a permission class for django rest api view.

this is my models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    auth_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Group(models.Model):
    admin = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='g_admin')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='g_mess')
```

I want only group admin can perform an action in particular pages, for this i am writing a permission class:

```
class IsGroupAdmin(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to Group Admin.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # return bool() do something here
```

I am going through trouble to write the permission class to check if group admin or not. i am facing issue coz, this is many to many field.

can anyone help me to write this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `User` from `request.user`. I don't know how you can get the `Group` from request (it may be in the request payload, it depends on your design) but lets assume that you pass the `Group` to the permission class, then it would be something like that:

```
class IsGroupAdmin(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to Group Admin.
    """
    def __init__(self, group):
        super().__init__()
        self.group = group

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return self.group.profile_set.filter(auth_user=request.user).any()
```

Note: If you can get the group from request so you don't need to pass `group` to the `IsGroupAdmin` class and this would be much easier. But if you cant do that and you'r going to use just the above permission class, you'r going to need the `partial` function. so you need to import it:

```
from functools import partial
```

And then in the views, initiate `permission_classes` like that:

```
permission_classes = [partial(IsGroupAdmin, group)]
```

However, I suggest you to use the easier way, cause I think the `group` must be in `request`. Lets say that `group` is in the request payload, then you must implement `IsGroupAdmin` as:

```
class IsGroupAdmin(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to Group Admin.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        group = request.data.get('group', '')
        return group.profile_set.filter(auth_user=request.user).any()
```

And use it just like a normal permission. (no need to use `partial` function)

Answer (score 0):

your data structure is wrong 
**admin** and **members** should be m2m with **user** not with **Profile**.

for permission, you have to make a query like
Group.objects.filter(admin__auth_user__id=request.id) the true else return flase.

use through table it will reduce your work and make some sort of flag which gives you an idea that request user is the admin or not(in User model use signal) so every time you don't have to fire a query in the database.